# OData query to get the results of two specific columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I stuck on how to get two specific columns of data. My query:

```
{site}/_api/web/lists('{site_guid}')/items?$select&fields eq meatballColor,meatballExplained
```

I only get 7 items coming back when it should be 14, wondering if my syntax is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

The correct syntax for a `$select` that returns only column values from two columns (using your example for column names) is:

```
{site}/_api/web/lists('{list_guid}')/items?$select=meatballColor,meatballExplained
```

but that is still going to return all the items in the list, which according to your screen shot looks like 7.

---

First, from the screenshot of the list that you provided, it looks like there are only 7 items in the list.  So when you say

> I only get 7 items coming back when it should be 14

If you are thinking that you should be getting 14 results because there are 7 list items but you are asking for 2 column values, so you are expecting `7 x 2 = 14` things, that's not how the results are going to come back.

You can use a `$select` in your oData query to limit the number of *columns* returned, but they are still going to be divided into separate objects that correlate to the *list items* that hold those values in those columns.  If you want to limit the number of overall *items* that get returned, you would need to use a `$filter` in order to only return the list items that match your specific criteria.

For instance, if you did a query on that list with no `$select` to restrict the columns:

```
{site}/_api/web/lists('{list_guid}')/items
```

you would get a result that looked something like this (although with a lot more fields/columns included, because there are a bunch of built-in hidden SharePoint fields):

```
{
    d: {
        results: [
            {                // <-- first list item object
                Title: "y",
                default: "up",
                meatballExplained: "Choice #1",
                meatballColor: "Green",
                // other built-in SP fields
            },
            {                // <-- second list item object
                Title: "u",
                default: "down",
                meatballExplained: "Choice #3",
                meatballColor: "Red",
                // other built-in SP fields
            },
            // and then the other 5 list item objects here
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, if you used a `$select` to limit the fields, you're still going to get a `results` array of 7 items, because you are not using a `$filter` to limit the number of items, however, you would see less data inside each list item object.

Your `$select` query is also not quite the right syntax.  Instead of

```
/items?$select&fields eq meatballColor,meatballExplained
```

what you want is

```
/items?$select=columnOneName,columnTwoName
```

so in your specific case

```
{site}/_api/web/lists('{list_guid}')/items?$select=meatballColor,meatballExplained
```

And the result you get from that will look something like

```
{
    d: {
        results: [
            {                // <-- first list item object
                meatballExplained: "Choice #1",
                meatballColor: "Green"
            },
            {                // <-- second list item object
                meatballExplained: "Choice #3",
                meatballColor: "Red"
            },
            // and then 5 more list item objects here
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice that `Title` and `default` are no longer included (since they are not part of the `$select`), but you still are going to get all 7 list items.

Now, if you used a `$filter` to limit the number of items based on certain criteria, you could do something like

```
{site}/_api/web/lists('{list_guid}')/items?$select=meatballColor,meatballExplained&$filter=meatballColor eq 'Yellow'
```

which is telling SharePoint "give me all the list items where `meatballColor` is Yellow (but not any others), but *only* give me the values of `meatballColor` and `meatballExplained` for those few list items."

What you would get would look something like

```
{
    d: {
        results: [    // <-- the 'results' array will only contain 2 items, not all 7
            {
                meatballExplained: "Choice #3",
                meatballColor: "Yellow"
            },
            {
                meatballExplained: "Choice #5",
                meatballColor: "Yellow"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```